# awk: Print string in file2 not matching with string file2

Tags: awk

I have two file with comma separated values, I want to remove all the strings in file1 matching with strings in file 2.

```
file1:
soap,cosmetics,june,hello,good

file2:
june,hello

output:
soap,cosmetics,good
```

I tried this, but not working. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help appreciated.

```
BEGIN {
    FS=","
}

NR==FNR {
    a[NR]=$0
    next
}

{
    for (j=1;j<=NF;j++) {
        split($0, d, ",")
        if (d[j] in a == 0) {
            line = (line ? line "," : "") d[j]
        }
    }
print line
line = ""
}
```

Comment: +1 You were close. Just a few minor things really (re strategy). Please see my answer.

Comment: The way to approach problems like this is to set the RS to whatever separates your records, then populate an array with the records from one file, and then check if each record from the other file already exists in that array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file2 file1
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=","
}

FNR==NR {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        a[$i]
    }
    next
}

{
    for(j=1;j<=NF;j++) {
        if (!($j in a)) {
            r = (r ? r FS : "") $j
        }
    }
}

END {
    print r
}
```

Results:

```
soap,cosmetics,good
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]; next } { for(j=1;j<=NF;j++) if (!($j in a)) r = (r ? r FS : "") $j } END { print r }' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ gawk -v RS='[,\n]' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a){o=o s $0;s=","} END{print o}' file2 file1
soap,cosmetics,good
```